# Aegir hosting_https commercial SSL cert

Tags: aegir

Similar to [Aegir no longer seems to be adding SSL info to apache config files for sites](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/274899/aegir-no-longer-seems-to-be-adding-ssl-info-to-apache-config-files-for-sites)

The documentation still mentions a way to use commercial certs: https://docs.aegirproject.org/usage/advanced/ssl/#commercial-certificates

I too have run into the problem aegir_https not working the same way regarding chain certs.

Running aegir3-provision/stable,stable,now 3.182

LE is not an option for our org unfortunately.

Is there a way to use commercial apache certs with aegir_https/hosting_https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated at the top of that documentation page, everything there is legacy and is no longer supported.

The feature request for being able to use commercial certificates with [Aegir HTTPS](https://www.drupal.org/project/hosting_https) (the officially supported way of running HTTPS now), is [Add a 'manual' Certificate implementation](https://www.drupal.org/project/hosting_https/issues/2936037).

So your options are either:

- Write a patch yourself (and upload it to the issue), or
- Pay us, the maintainers, (or someone else) to do it for you.

Comment: Gotcha, I figured as much but had to ask. Thanks for all the excellent work and long hours y'all put in!